# How to handle a non deletable resource when implementing a terraform provider

Tags: terraform

I am currently working on trying to manage a resource with Terraform that has no delete method, and terraform insists there must be one.

```
  1 error occurred:
            * resource xray_db_sync_time: Delete must be implemented
```

The API I am trying to implement is [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Xray+REST+API#XrayRESTAPI-UpdateDBSyncDailyUpdateTime), and as you can see, there is no "Delete". You can't remove this sync timer. I am open to ideas. The code being worked on is [here](https://github.com/jfrog/terraform-provider-xray/pull/35)

Comment: I think you have to [remove](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/state/rm) from your state file prior destruction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a situation where you, as the provider developer, will need to make a judgement call about how best to handle this mismatch between Terraform's typical resource instance lifecycle and the *actual* lifecycle of the object type you're intending to represent.

Broadly speaking, there are two options:

- You could make the `Delete` function immediately return an error, explaining that this object is not deleteable. This could be an appropriate approach if the user might be surprised or harmed by the object continuing to exist even though Terraform has no record of it. I would informally call this the "explicit approach", because it makes the user aware that something unusual is happening and requires them to explicitly confirm that they want Terraform to just "forget" the rather than destroying it, using `terraform state rm`.
- You could make the `Delete` function just call `d.SetId("")` (indicating to the SDK that the object no longer exists) and return successfully without taking any other action. I'll call this the "implicit approach", because a user not paying close attention may be fooled into thinking the object was actually deleted, due to the provider not giving any feedback that it just silently discarded the object.

Both of these options have advantages and disadvantages, and so ultimately the final decision is up to you. Terraform and its SDK will support either strategy, but you will need to implement *some* sort of `Delete` function, even if it doesn't do anything, to satisfy the API contract.

Comment: I like the explicit approach and Was thinking that CREATE and DEL should both produce errors. If a user wants that resource managed in TF then they can import it, which would invoke GET

Comment: You can implement `Create` to return an error too, if you wish... a similar tradeoff applies as for `Delete`, although importing is a little more arduous than "forgetting" due to the need to look up a suitable ID to use, but I think both are valid in that case too though; if you choose to be explicit in both cases then I'd suggest being clear in the documentation about how exactly the user ought to employ `terraform import` and `terraform state rm` to bypass the error messages, to reduce the risk of someone getting stuck and being unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: Can I get a question upvote?

Answer (score 1):

You are also missing a Create for this API endpoint. With only Update and Read supported, you will need to extend Create to be the same as Update except for additionally adding the resource to the state. You can easily invoke the Update function within the Create function for this behavior.

For the delete function, this should actually be easier than you may expect. The Terraform provider SDKv2 and your resource code should automatically Read the resource prior to attempting the delete to verify that it actually exists (this probably requires no extra effort on your part without seeing the code). Then you would need to remove the resource from the state with `d.SetId("")` where `d` is of type `*schema.ResourceData`. However, this also automatically is invoked assuming the Delete returns no errors. Therefore, you could define a Delete that merely returns warnings or errors of an appropriate Go type. If you do not need that (and probably would not considering the minimal functionality), then you could probably just `return nil`. Part of this is speculation based on what your code probably looks like, but in general this all holds true.

Comment: I'll update the question with a link to the provider so you can have a glance